# Best way to apply the CSS class in the same template on the basis of true and false

Tags: html, css, salesforce-lightning

I need to call the CSS class from the same template on the
basis of the true and false.

below is the code.

```
<template if:true={extraction}>
    <div class='animationRight'>
        <c-data-base></c-data-base>
    </div>
</template>

CSS Class:
 animateright
 animateopposite
```

as above similarly when i am calling the CSS class animateright when extraction is true. how can i call the 'animateopposite ' when CSS class extraction if false?

i need to do in the same template. is there any way to do it?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are using vuejs?

Comment: its salesforce LWC